# Screenshot and Video are appearing blank in cypress

Tags: screenshot, cypress

When I run test cases in cypress, am getting screenshots and video as blank

Operating System: Windows 10
Cypress version: 3.1.3
Browser: Electron 59 (headless)

I have tried installing cypress, node with admin profile. But still facing the same issue.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please read:[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

I believe cypress still got an issue with recording of blank videos in windows environment, please see the bug detail.

https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1304

But before that, double check your screenshot and video settings in cypress settings:

For `screenshots` please check the `configuration` settings are looking good;

```
screenshotsFolder   cypress/screenshots 
trashAssetsBeforeRuns   true
```

The same for `video`

```
video: true,
videoCompression: 32,
videoUploadOnPasses: true,
videosFolder: 'cypress/videos'
```